# Getting text from programmatically added EditText by id

Tags: java, android, view

I have a series of programmatically added EditTexts in a Linearlayout with id's that I assigned using the

```
int id = 100;
EditText field =  new EditText(getActivity());
field.setId(id);
```

I need to get the text from the EditText's and I keep getting nullPointerException  when I try to get the text from it.

```
EditText temp = (EditText)view.findViewById(id);
ans = ans+Double.parseDouble(temp.getText().toString());
```

Also the view is in a fragment if that makes any difference.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

just make the `field` as a member variable instead a local variable. Or make sure that `view` is the view where you have added your `field`

Answer (score 0):

declare the id variable private and keep adding edittext with id++ and then we trying to fetch the id you can fetch EditText's until you get a null pointer exception.